# Check for some condition and output a new variable in R

Tags: r

The sample data I have is as follows,

```
main_data = data.frame(var1 = c('abd_cde', 'BPCS', 'POIU', 'CDRD', 'UPqw', 'qwer')),
```

main_data

```
     var1
1 abd_cde
2    BPCS
3    POIU
4    CDRD
5    UPqw
6    qwer
```

I have the following code where I want to check some conditions in one variable and output another variable. The following is the code I have written,

```
main_data$var2 = 0

for (i in 1:nrow(main_data)) {
  if(grepl("_", main_data$var1[i]) == TRUE){
    main_data$var2[i] = "1"
  }
  else if((substr(main_data$var1[i], 1, 1) == 'B') | (substr(main_data$var1[i], 1, 1) == 'C') ){
    main_data$var2[i] = "2"
  }
  else if((substr(main_data$var1[i], 1, 1) == 'P') | (substr(main_data$var1[i], 1, 1) == 'U') ){
    main_data$var2[i] = "3"
  }

}
```

To give the gist of the code, If a variable contains "_", I want to output 1, if it starts with B or C, want to output 2 and if it starts with P or U, want to output 3.

But this code is taking a lot of time to run because I have around 2 million records to run. Is there a way we can make this efficient?

My ideal output would be,

```
     var1   var2
1 abd_cde     1
2    BPCS     2
3    POIU     3
4    CDRD     2
5    UPqw     3
6    qwer     0
```

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make this into a reproducible example? Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What if none of the conditions in your list are satisfied?

Comment: @Psidom I have 0 as the base one, If none of them are satisfied, it would be 0

Comment: @Hack-R Sure . will change it now. Thanks

Comment: @Hack-R changed it now. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Great nice work, much improved +1

Comment: The first thing I would consider to improve is replace `substr(...1,1)...` with `startWith()` since according to `?startWith()` , `startsWith() is equivalent to but much faster than substring(x, 1, nchar(prefix)) == prefix`.

Comment: @Psidom sure will do that. But I am thinking, there should be a way to avoid this for loop here. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: I would at least try `ifelse()` statement, even though it is not very fast either. Also I would avoid seeking the element multiple times as you've done here. For example, I would do `tmpVar = main_data$var1[i]` and then use `tmpVar` for condition checking.

Comment: For example. You can try this: `dplyr::mutate(main_data, var2 = ifelse(grepl("_", var1), 1, ifelse(grepl("^B|^C", var1), 2, ifelse(grepl("^P|^U", var1), 3, 0))))`.

Comment: Alternatively use `data.table` package. `setDT(main_data)[, var2 := ifelse(grepl("_", var1), 1, ifelse(grepl("^B|^C", var1), 2, ifelse(grepl("^P|^U", var1), 3, 0)))]` which is known to be fast.

Comment: @Psidom - `startsWith` might be quicker, but the gains are miniscule for all but the largest data - `system.time(substr(rep("aaaaaaaaaaa",10e6),1,1))` takes 0.7 seconds over here. That's 10M records in 3/4s of a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine this into a single expression (e.g. using multiple `ifelse` statements), but this is pretty easy to read and should be faster than looping:

```
> x <- c("foo_bar", "x_y", "Bxx", "Cxx", "Pzz", "Uzz")
> x[grepl('_', x)] <- 1
> x[grepl('^[BC]', x)] <- 2
> x[grepl('^[PU]', x)] <- 3

> x
[1] "1" "1" "2" "2" "3"
```

If you just wanted to test for strings starting with a single letter, the `startsWith` function would also work.

Answer (score 3):

If you need speed, Rcpp is an option. A lot can be accomplished with the Rcpp library in combination with the C++ standard library. For example, here's how we can implement your requirement using [`std::strchr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) to find the underscore, some array indexing, char comparisons, and a ternary chain:

```
library(Rcpp);
cppFunction(includes='#include <cstring>','
    IntegerVector f1(CharacterVector x) {
        IntegerVector res(x.size());
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
            res[i] =
                std::strchr(x[i],\'_\') ? 1 :
                (c = x[i][0])==\'B\' || c==\'C\' ? 2 :
                c==\'P\' || c==\'U\' ? 3 :
                0
            ;
        return res;
    }
');

f1(main_data$var1);
## [1] 1 2 3 2 3 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr`'s latest version (0.5.0) comes with a new `case_when` function that makes the nasty nesting `ifelse` structure unnecessary. You can implement it with `startsWith` (HT @Psidom) or plain old `grepl`:

```
library(dplyr)

              # string functions don't like factors
main_data %>% mutate(var1 = as.character(var1)) %>% 
    # for each case (in order), if the left side is true, return the right side
    mutate(var2 = case_when(grepl('_', .$var1, fixed = TRUE) ~ 1, 
                            startsWith(.$var1, 'B') | startsWith(.$var1, 'C') ~ 2, 
                            startsWith(.$var1, 'P') | startsWith(.$var1, 'U') ~ 3, 
                            TRUE ~ 0))

#      var1 var2
# 1 abd_cde    1
# 2    BPCS    2
# 3    POIU    3
# 4    CDRD    2
# 5    UPqw    3
# 6    qwer    0

# or with grepl (results are identical)
main_data %>% mutate(var1 = as.character(var1)) %>% 
    mutate(var2 = case_when(grepl('_', .$var1, fixed = TRUE) ~ 1, 
                            grepl('^[BC]', .$var1) ~ 2, 
                            grepl('^[PU]', .$var1) ~ 3, 
                            TRUE ~ 0))
```

Note the `.$var1` notation, which is odd for `dplyr`, but seems to be necessary for some reason.

It seem fairly snappy, too; `dplyr` tries to run a lot in C, which it seems to be here. Just run on the test set (obviously not realistic) against @bgoldst's Rcpp and @Psidom's data.table from the comments:

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 startsWith 1285.372 1384.862 1593.404 1478.276 1689.269  6547.404   100
      grepl 1260.778 1395.494 1575.984 1509.890 1752.506  2258.982   100
       rcpp 3783.274 4101.735 4562.076 4361.927 4637.183 10818.012   100
 data.table  913.635 1069.397 1180.042 1135.440 1290.791  1567.259   100
```

Resampled to 100,000 rows (possibly still not representative, depending on what's happening under the hood), Rcpp predictably pulls away:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
 startsWith 21.288367  27.555653  30.904011  29.611775  34.269493  40.80770   100
      grepl 57.025665  60.209641  63.748722  62.204733  66.900175  73.81332   100
       rcpp  8.090686   8.545949   9.419899   8.764327   9.567707  24.65368   100
 data.table 92.093603 100.449884 107.358620 104.229641 107.240123 240.52098   100
```

Times are similar regardless of whether `var1` is factor or character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simpler way using String functions in R. This is similar to what Keith has mentioned.

```
main_data = data.frame(var1 = c('abd_cde', 'BPCS', 'POIU', 'CDRD', 'UPqw', 'qwer'))
main_data$var2<-ifelse(grepl("_",main_data$var1),1,ifelse(grepl("B.*|C.*",main_data$var1),2,ifelse(grepl("P.*|U.*",main_data$var1),3,0)))
```

Here, I have used ifelse() to go over all the rows and give the result you wanted.